# How to read full info in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Info]

Is there any way to show this full message as I have a long project directory path? I want to fix this .eslintrc error. I've tried click it and hover on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open bug in VSCode, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31815) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22388).
Currently no wrapping support for text.
Should be addressed this month.